# Object oriented java sample exam

Tags: java, oop

```
public class Bird
{
  private static int id = 0;
  private String kind;

  public Bird(String requiredKind)
  {
    id = id + 1;
    kind = requiredKind;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    return "Kind: " + kind + ", Id: " + id + "; ";
  }

  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    Bird [] birds = new Bird[2];
    birds[0] = new Bird("falcon");
    birds[1] = new Bird("eagle");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    System.out.print(birds[i]);
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

This is a question from a sample exam, The output is asked and the correct answer is 
Kind: falcon, Id: 2; Kind: eagle, Id: 2;

I didn't understand why id is 2 and it is same for both instances. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `id` field is static,  it will have the same value throughout (and outside of) all instances of `Bird`.

After creating two `Bird` objects, the constructor will have been called twice, therefore the `id` will be `2`.

See: [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 0):

because here `private static int id = 0;` id is declared [static or class variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html). Static variables are class variable they are not initialized or created every time an object is created.

So, only one copy of static variable exist. No, new copies are created when object are created using `new` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `id` is `static`. That means that is a "Class variable/field" and there is only one per Class. All the instances of that Class share it the same `id` (indeed calling it "id" feels kinda weird).

See [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

static variables are shared across objects unlike instance variables. So when this executes

```
birds[0] = new Bird("falcon");
```

the `id` increments to 1. After that the below is executed incrementing it to 2

```
birds[1] = new Bird("eagle");
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to static variable 'for' loop only put

```
System.out.print(birds[i]);
```

not

```
System.out.println(birds[i]);
```

so until end of execute 'for' loop it print only one Line because 'for' loop have not {} bracket it loop only one line

Answer (score -1):

because we are calling `toString` in the end. When `toString` takes value of `id` to return its always 2.
Better to print references one by one .